# How to monitor what the user clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently having trouble figuring out how am i supposed to monitor every click of the user.

My little game does this :

You have **5 buttons**, **1 start button** and **4 buttons** that will be `highlighted` in **a random order**.

After that i want the user to click the buttons in the order that they have been highlighted (in 10 seconds time, i haven't implemented the 10 seconds time yet).

I don't know how to restrict the user to only be able to press buttons only in the given time and to see what buttons he presses just with JavaScript and Jquery (if you can't restrict at least to see what buttons he presses ).

I will then retain the order in which he pressed the buttons in the array "input" .

Here is my code :

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="ro"> 
<head> 
<link href="my.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript"  src="jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script src="Joculet.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> Joculet </title>
 </head>

<body>
<div id ='tot'>
<button type='button' class='cls1' id='id1'></button>

<button type='button' class='cls2' id='id2'></button>

<button type='button' class='cls3' id='id3'></button>

<button type='button' class='cls4' id='id4'></button>

<button type='button' id='start'>Click Me!</button> 
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.tot{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    }

.cls1{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    width: 12%;
    height: 12%;
    border: 2px solid black;

   }

.cls2{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 12%;
    height: 12%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin-left: 17%;

   }

.cls3{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #00FF00;
    width: 12%;
    height: 12%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin-top: 12%;

   }

.cls4{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #3090C7;
    width: 12%;
    height: 12%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin-left: 17%;
    margin-top: 12%;

   }

#start{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 12%;
    margin-top: 23%;

    }

.cls12{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #C24641;
    width: 12%;
    height: 12%;
    border: 2px solid black;

    }

.cls22{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #FFFFCC;
    width: 12%;
    height: 12%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin-left: 17%;

   }

.cls32{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #6AFB92;
    width: 12%;
    height: 12%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin-top: 12%;

   }

.cls42{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #893BFF;
    width: 12%;
    height: 12%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin-left: 17%;
    margin-top: 12%;

   }
```

and the most important JS :

```
    var k = 1;
    var g = 1;
    var nrmax = 8;
    ordine = new Array();
    var j = 0;
    input = new Array();

    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#start').click(function () {
        game();
    })

    function game() {
        if(k <= nrmax){
            if(g <= k){
                var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
                ordine[j++] = x;
                change1(x);
            }
            else {
                    alert('Felicitari ai castigat runda');
                    g = 1;
                    k++;
                    j = 0;
                    ordine = new Array();
                    setTimeout(function(){game();},2000);
                }
        }
        else alert('Felicitari ai castigat jocul');

    }

    function change1(y) {
        var z = 'cls' + y;
        var t = 'cls' + y + 2;
        $("." + z).removeClass(z).addClass(t);
        setTimeout(function() { change2(y); }, 500);
    }

    function change2(y) {
        var z = 'cls' + y + 2;
        var t = 'cls' + y;
        $("." + z).removeClass(z).addClass(t);
        g++;
        setTimeout(function(){game();},500);
    }

});
```

any help is apreciated, you can also find the code here for a better view http://jsfiddle.net/6qDap/1181/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understood your questions correctly. I did not include the timer but here is how you could maintain the order of clicked buttons in the input array.

http://jsfiddle.net/6qDap/1184/

```
        $('button').click(function(){
            input.push( $(this).attr('id') );
            console.log(input);
        });
```

Don't forget to check the console to view the output. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions or if I misunderstood.

Comment: Not a problem! If this solved your problem don't forget to mark this answer as correct. Thanks!

Comment: Oh! I totally forgot about that! Thanks though, and glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right - you want to time a user clicking 4 buttons within 10 sec. I would start a javascript timer when the user clicks start.

```
setTimeout(disablebuttonsaftertimeout, 10000);
```

Then disable the buttons after the timer expires.

Answer (score 0):

"I don't know how to restrict the user to only be able to press buttons only in the given time and to see what buttons he presses" - **are asking two things here**

- I don't know how to restrict the user to only be able to press buttons only in the given time - **if time is over, disable/hide buttons**
- see what buttons he presses - **every time he presses a button store the id of a button in the array**
- **also to restrict the user from pressing any other buttons, add a class "wrong" to buttons that he can't press and on click check** `if $(this).hasClass('wrong') return 0;`